# IIS WCF webservice and mutual authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis-7

I have a C# based WCF RESTful webservice in IIS7 running on Windows Server 2008. The webservice accepts XML data via HTTPS POST only. customBinding is being used. I have checked "Require SSL" in the SSL Settings option and also selected the option of "Require" in that same page.

During the SSL handshake, however, I do not see the server sending a `CertificateRequest` (ssl.handshake.type = 13) request from the Server. I can only see a (`ServerHello`, `Certificate`, `ServerHelloDone`). After the `ServerHelloDone` message there is a "Bad Certificate" message in the wireshark capture.

Can someone please help ? The relevant part of the binding in Web.Config file contents are as follows :

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    ...
    <binding name="RawReceiveCapableHttps">
      <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="e000webapp1.RawContentTypeMapper, e000webapp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" requireClientCertificate="true" />
      <!-- security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" /> 
      </security -->
    </binding> 
  </customBinding>    
</bindings>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know WCF well enough to provide an answer. But [Mutual authentication with a IIS hosted WCF data service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bradleycotier/archive/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment.aspx) might be helpful for you.